# How to set 'EC2 StopInstances' API call as EventBridge target using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to write a Cloudformation template which creates an EventBridge rule.

The EventBridge rule is supposed to stop an instance based on a schedule.

EventBridge target is expected as `arn` parameter in Cloudformation template. I couldn't figure out the `arn` value of the rule.

This is the template snippet I use:

```
 {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09"
    "Resources": {
        ...
        "Ec2StartStopRule": {
            "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "ec2-stop-start-rule",
                "RoleArn": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "Ec2StopStartRoleForEventBridge",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "ScheduleExpression": "cron(0 12 * * ? *)",
                "Targets": [
                    {
                        "Arn": "ec2:StopInstances",
                        "Id": "Id1234",
                        "RunCommandParameters": {
                            "RunCommandTargets": [
                                {
                                    "Key": "InstanceIds",
                                    "Values": [
                                        "mydata"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "RetryPolicy": {
                            "MaximumRetryAttempts": 2,
                            "MaximumEventAgeInSeconds": 3600
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive following error:

> Parameter ec2:StopInstances is not valid. Reason: Provided Arn is not in correct format.

I am sure EventBridge supports EC2 StopInstances API call as target: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html

But I cannot configure it using Cloudformation.

How to set 'EC2 StopInstances' API call as EventBridge target using Cloudformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Please see this link:

[AWS docs on target support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutTargets.html#:%7E:text=Creating%20rules%20with%20built%2Din%20targets%20is%20supported%20only%20in%20the%20AWS%20Management%20Console.%20The%20built%2Din%20targets%20are%20EC2%20CreateSnapshot%20API%20call%2C%20EC2%20RebootInstances%20API%20call%2C%20EC2%20StopInstances%20API%20call%2C%20and%20EC2%20TerminateInstances%20API%20call.)

I would recommend to run a lambda as target and run the api call through it.

Comment: Ok. As the document says, "Creating rules with built-in targets is supported only in the AWS Management Console. The built-in targets are EC2 CreateSnapshot API call, EC2 RebootInstances API call, EC2 StopInstances API call, and EC2 TerminateInstances API call."

Answer (score -1):

```
"Targets": [{
    "Id": "<your-id>",
    "Arn": { "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:events:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:target/stop-instance" },
    "RoleArn": { "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam:${AWS::AccountId}:role/<your-iam-role>" },
    "Input": "\"<your-instance-id>\""
}]
```

Comment: Could you describe your answer? Have you seen @Eric's answer? He points out that it is not possible to set 'EC2 StopInstances' API call as EventBridge target using Cloudformation?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34685955)

Comment: @WaleedTariq: Why do you say that? This certainly appears to be an attempt to answer to me.